# Generator of prime ideal of ring of integers of $ \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be ring of integers of $ \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-3})$.
$R$ is PID, so every prime ideal of $R$ can be written as the form $(π)$.
So far, so good.

But from here, I'm stuck with.
I heard there is unique $π$ such that $π≡2\pmod3$. How can I find such $π$ and why $π$ is unique ?

I should find appropriate unit of $R$,which is

{$±1,±ω,±ω^2$}, where $ω$ is primitive $3$-th root of unity..

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is only true for prime ideals coprime to $(3)$. What you do is pick any $\pi$ and mutliply it by the six units. One of them will be $\equiv 2 \bmod 3$ (because there are six  coprime residues classes modulo $3$ and each one is generated by a unit).

Comment: What is the six caprice residues classes modulo $3$ ? Residue classes modulo $3$ is jut $0,1,2$ ?

Comment: The quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]/(3)$ has $9$ elements, $6$ of which are units (and powers of $-\omega$). Iff $(\pi)$ is coprime to $(3)$ then its image in $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]/(3)$ is a unit.